# Why do Python decorators do this? Different Output?

Tags: python, function, output, decorator, python-3.7

I am relatively *new* to **Python** and I was messing around with decorators and I found myself stuck on how to explain the output I was getting after running a decorated function.
Here's the code:

**I first defined a function add like this**

```
def add(a, b):
    '''Returns the sum of two numbers a and b'''
    return a + b
```

**I then created a decorator like so**

```
def decorator_function(somefunction): 
    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        return f'{somefunction(*args, **kwargs)}!!!'
    return wrapper_function

@decorator_function
def add(a, b):
    '''Returns the sum of two numbers a and b and since it is decorated it is going to return the 
    result with 3 !!!'''
    return a + b
```

**I then ran the function add like so and got the following output**

```
>>> add(5, 15)
'20!!!'
```

**I then ran the function like so and got a different output**

```
>>> result = decorator_function(add)
>>> result(5, 15)
'20!!!!!!'        # Why did I get 6 '!'
>>> add = decorator_function(add)
>>> add(5, 15)
'20!!!!!!'        # Why did I get 6 '!'?
```

> **Now I don't understand why I got 6 exclamation marks**

Comment: add is already decorated.  So by calling `decorator_function(add)`, you are decorating it a second time.

Comment: Yes I see it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You already have decorated your add function with

```
@decorator_function
```

If you write later write

```
decorator_function(add)
```

it is actually:

```
decorator_function(decorator_function(add))
```

Comment: Mark that reply as the correct answer then so others can easily know it's fixed.